# git discard all changes and pull from upstream

Tags: git

How do I fetch upstream repo and make it replace master? I only have one branch on my repo, which is master, and I completely messed it up, so I basically need to start over from the upstream. I think init will do the job, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 363):

There are (at least) two things you can do here–you can reclone the remote repo, or you can `reset --hard` to the common ancestor and then do a pull, which will fast-forward to the latest commit on the remote master.

To be concrete, here's a simple extension of Nevik Rehnel's original answer:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull origin master
```

**NOTE**: using `git reset --hard` will discard any uncommitted changes, and it can be easy to confuse yourself with this command if you're new to git, so make sure you have a sense of what it is going to do before proceeding.

Comment: More help for the rookies out there: `git gc` cleans up and runs thru some housekeeping. On another note, I have never run `git gc`.  It is nice to run, but not needed.

Comment: @JoshuaDance -- good point.  I'm not sure why I originally included it.

Answer (score 31):

You can do it in a single command:

```
git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Notes:

1 WARNING **you will lose ALL your local changes**

2 if you want a branch different than `master` you have to use:

```
git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/[BRANCH]
```

3 you can split it in a pair of commands:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 28):

while on branch master:
`git reset --hard origin/master`

then do some clean up with `git gc` (more about this in the man pages)

Update: You will also probably need to do a `git fetch origin` (or `git fetch origin master` if you **only** want that branch); it should not matter if you do this before or after the reset. (Thanks @eric-walker)

Comment: You might need to do a pull after the `reset --hard`.

Comment: Pulling from master is not necessary once git fetch origin is run before the reset.

Comment: @sciritai: my comment was added before the mention of fetching from origin.

Answer (score 13):

I finally realized now that instead of

```
git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master
```

it should be

```
git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

instead (if one works on a different branch)

Comment: In the meantime this was added to [Luca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220797/1269037) so this answer has become unnecessary. Would be nice to delete it - you'll get a badge!

Answer (score 8):

```
git reset <hash>  # you need to know the last good hash, so you can remove all your local commits

git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
git push origin master -f
```

voila, now your fork is back to same as upstream.

Comment: This is the best answer to solve origin (fork) vs upstream inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

With more recent versions of git, this might be the easiest way:

```
git restore * && git pull
```

Comment: I get a bunch of `error: pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any file(s) known to git` errors for existing files/directories that are in `.gitignore`.

Comment: This does not work, got the error mentioned in the earlier message

Answer (score -2):

While all of these answer propose different ways, that have different possible failure modes based on different assumptions.

What I always do is

1. delete the local repository
2. clone a new copy

This ALWAYS works and there is no mess left around to cause conflicts in the future.  These operations are well documented, whereas some of the others mentioned have meager explanation for exactly what will happen.  Cloning a new repository is simple, it is effective, and it does not cause errors in obscure situations.

Comment: do you throw out your computer out of the window and order a new one as well? That's also quite effective, ALWAYS works and there is no mess left around for the future that way. /s

Comment: I don't think anyone is impressed by your need to resort to name calling.