# How to commit major changes to a Git repository that have been made outside this repo?

Tags: git

Suppose that the following has happened:

1. A git repo hasn't been updated in a year. In this year, someone else majorly revised the code in their own copy.
2. You want to update the repo with their code revisions, so these changes show in the commit history going forwards.
3. You thus get a copy of their code, run `git remote add origin https://github.com/account/repo-name.git`, and try pushing that code to the repo.

This push will fail with the error "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally"

So, how can you achieve the goal in step 2?

Comment: Did you incorporate their changes into a dedicated branch? What branch are you trying to push the changes to? master?

Comment: > Did you incorporate their changes into a dedicated branch?

No - is that part of the solution?

> What branch are you trying to push the changes to? master? 

Yes, master

Comment: The problem here is that work has been done in the master branch on the server since you committed. So that work must be merged into your local copy of the master branch before you can push additional changes to master. You'd need to do a `git pull` to get the changes from remote to local. However, since you mentioned major revisions, it's likely you'll have merge conflicts. You'll need to solve those before you can then `git push`. Of course, this is all risky and it'd be far better if you did these changes to a separate branch, then used a pull request to get the changes into master.

Comment: ...that would help you review the code prior to merging and give you a clearer idea of exactly what is changing.

Comment: OK - I don't really understand git branches but I'll try reading up and doing that! Unless you have any pointers. :) But if not, thanks for your help already.

Comment: Branches are easy, and a major selling point for Git. While working in master is fine for simple scenarios, you should take the time to work in a separate branch normally so that you can PR your code into master and review the changes to make sure you haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Create a branch at **exactly** the revision where the person who worked separately started working from. Then remove every single file from it (use `git rm` for removing).... then put there whatever the user code is.... then add all of that and commit (use `--author="batman forever"` with the name of the developer so that you know who really did it), and then you can use this work to be merged or whatever you consider should be done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that work has been done in the master branch on the server since you committed. So that work must be merged into your local copy of the master branch before you can push additional changes to master.

You've already committed the 3rd party's (let's call that dev John Doe) changes to your master branch. That's not a good idea. You haven't reviewed it yet.

A simple way to undo this would be to delete the repo off your machine, then reclone it down. Of course, only do this if your local repo doesn't have any work that's missing from the remote copy. Another option would be to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781388/git-discard-all-changes-and-pull-from-upstream) to reset your local master to what's on the server.

Then, on your local repo, create a new branch to perform the changes from. This branch should start out with the same HEAD as master.

```
#make sure we base our work off master
git checkout master

#create a new branch to contain the changes and switch to it
git checkout -b feature/john-doe-changes

#push the branch up to the server
git push -u origin feature/john-doe-changes
```

Then, take the code from the other developer, and integrate it with your current code base.

Once you're done and it's working how you want, commit the changes and push them up to the server.

```
git commit -m "Integrated code from John Doe"
git push
```

At this point you can go to GitHub's site and open a PR. The source branch is `feature/john-doe-changes` and the target branch is `master`. Review the PR to make sure you're satisfied with it. Have other devs on your team review it if that's your company's practice or they're available to do it.

If any changes are necessary, make them locally, then commit and push them up to the server.

Then complete the PR, which will merge the changes from `feature/john-doe-changes` to `master` on the server.

Then on your local repo, you can clean up.

```
#switch to master
git checkout master

#pull changes from remote master to your local master
git pull

#update your remote references
git fetch --prune

#remove the feature branch, it's not needed anymore
git branch -d feature/john-doe-changes
```